# Extbase: Command Controller is not getting Registered

Tags: extbase

I am new to Extbase. There are two xml files that I want to access. One is abc.dll?type=xml from which I select the ID and then use this Id to fetch the values of other XML file(xyzzy.dll?type=xml and save all the data to the db. I want to create a task in Extbase and run it from command line.

Below is my code:

- ext_localconf.php

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][] = 'TYPO3\Example\Command\XMLFetcherCommandController';

- XMLFetcherCommandController:

  ```
  namespace TYPO3\Example\Command;

  class XMLFetcherCommandController extends \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\CommandController{
      /**
       * xmlload
       *
       * @return void
       */
      public function findCommand(){
          $path="http://abc.dll?type=room&content=xml";
          $readXML=file_get_contents($path);
          $xml = simplexml_load_string($readXML, "SimpleXMLElement",LIBXML_NOCDATA);      $objectManager=\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
          $classesRepository = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\\Example\\Domain\\Repository\\ClassesRepository');
          $json=json_encode($xml);
          $xmlArray=json_decode($json,true);
          $serialized_array = serialize($xmlArray); 
          $unserialized_array = unserialize($serialized_array);
          $rooms = $unserialized_array['Rooms']['Room'];
          foreach($rooms as $room){
           $fetchXML= \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\Example\\Domain\\Model\\Classes');
           $fetchXML->setRoomKey($room['Key']);
           $fetchXML->setRoomID($room['ID']);
           $classesRepository->add($fetchXML);
           $newpaths[]='http:/xyz.dll?content=xml&type=room&id='.$room['ID'];

           foreach($newpaths as $newpath){
              $readLessons=file_get_contents($newpath);
              $xmlLessons= simplexml_load_string($readLessons, "SimpleXMLElement",LIBXML_NOCDATA);
              $objectManager=\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
              $classesRepository = $objectManager->get('Example\\Example\\Domain\\Repository\\ClassesRepository');
               $json=json_encode($xml);
              $xmlArray=json_decode($json,true);
              $serialized_array = serialize($xmlArray); 
              $unserialized_array = unserialize($serialized_array);
              $Lessons = $unserialized_array['Lesson'];
              foreach ($Lessons as $Lesson) {
                  $fetchXMLNew= \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Example\\Example\\Domain\\Model\\Classes');
                  $date=date('Ymd',strtotime($Lesson['Date']));
                  $start=date('Hi',strtotime($Lesson['Start']));
                  $finish=date('Hi',strtotime($Lesson['Finish']));
                  $startdatetime=date('YmdHi',strtotime("$date$start"));
                  $finishdatetime=date('YmdHi',strtotime("$date$finish"));
                  $fetchXMLNew->setStartdatetime($startdatetime);
                  $fetchXMLNew->setEnddatetime($finishdatetime);
                  $classesRepository->add($fetchXML);

                                   }
            }
          }
               $classesRepository->persistAll();
              }
      }
  }

  ?>

  When I run-  php cli_dispatch.phpsh extbase help - from cmd, I could not see my command controller which means it is not registered properly. Could you suggest if this is the right way to do it? At First, I created a Service and tried to call it, but since there was a lot of data it was taking a lot of time.
  ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it does not work, becouse your class can not be loaded with autoloader?

If a class is not available, it will not be registerd. 
(@see CommandManager->getAvailableCommands !class_exists($className)).

I think you need to escape the back slashes (=> Double Slashes)

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['SC_OPTIONS']['extbase']['commandControllers'][]
= 'TYPO3\\Example\\Command\\XMLFetcherCommandController';
```

If this not work, you can also check the Namespace of your class. Why does it start with "TYPO3"?

If this also not work, you can try load your class hardcoded with require_once in AdditionalConfiguration.php to figure out whats wrong

Comment: I will try to include that along with double slashes. In the Namespace TYPO3\Example\Command\XMLFetcherCommandController: Please ignore the TYPO3, the correct Namesapce is Blog\Example\Command\XMLFetcherCommandController. I am really sorry for the mess up.

Comment: It Worked!! Thank you so much Steffen.